# Recompile a decompiled class from a plugin

Tags: java, jar, minecraft, bukkit, recompile

I am building a server in MC and I managed to change the plugin the way I wanted and now I want to compile that changed .java file to get the .class file and run the plugin on my server. However, I can't figure out how to recompile that specific .java file to generate the new .class file. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My process:

1. Get the .jar of the plugin and change it to .zip to get the src of the jar
2. Decompile the class I want to edit, copy the code into a new .java file and delete the .class
3. (Where I fail) Recompile the .java file to generate the .class
4. zip the folder and change it to .jar

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but here's how I do it:

1. Open the plugin in JD-GUI (Yes, you'll need to download it)
2. File>Save Source, Resource or whatever.
3. It will be saved as Winrar from what I remember, what you're going to want to do is extract that folder into your Eclipse workspace folder.
4. Create a new java project, and name the project whatever the folder you extracted was called.
5. It should say there is already a .project or whatever and you'll just want to click finish.
6. Change things around and add dependencies.